# in html video source need to play video on specific time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, video

I have video in my source. It's named Video1.mp4 and has a duration of about 5:00.

If the user enters the time, from  2:00 to 3:00 ', video need start 2:00 End in  3:00 min mark. Is that possible in PHP or jQuery?

Comment: It's possible. You will need to use JS to achieve it. If you would like specific help on how to do it, please edit your question to include your current HTML and JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5 you need wait for the browser to load the video's metadata.

```
document.getElementById('videoBlock').addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
 this.currentTime = 120;
}, false);
```

Jquery:

```
var video = $('#videoBlock');
video.on('loadedmetadata', function () {
   this.currentTime = 120;
});
```

Comment: i have edited the question thanks it works dude  can pause at specific time...? in jquery

Comment: @kamalraj added Jquery on my answer.

Comment: to pause at a certain time you would want an event watcher (`video.on`) that tracks `timeupdate` and checks if the `currenttime > 3*60` and then pauses